# node-fetch not working with AWS lambda function ("cannot find node-fetch")

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Basically I am trying to invoke a lambda function from an API Gateway. The API is called from an index.html file I made that calls the api with a button click and returns values (ideally the weather). I can get it to return some text values but whenever I try to actually call an API with the lambda function using node-fetch function it gives me an error saying "cannot find node-fetch module."

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports.getTulsaCurrentWeather = (event, context, callback) => {

//API endpoint
const endpoint = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
APPID=${process.env.APPID}&q=Tulsa&units=imperial`;

fetch(endpoint)
.then( res => res.json() )
.then( body =>  {
const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ temperature: body.main.temp })
};

callback(null, response);
});
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How do I build a Lambda deployment package for Node.js?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-nodejs/)

> A common error with Lambda functions in Node.js is "cannot find
> module." This error is usually caused when your deployment package
> doesn't have the correct folder structure for the Lambda service to
> load your modules and libraries, or it has incorrect file permissions.
> (Lambda requires global read permissions.)
>
> Follow [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-nodejs/) to build a deployment package that includes
> the function code in the root of the .zip file with read and execute
> permissions for all files.

Note that your code wouldn't run outside of Lambda either, for example on your own machine, unless you had previously installed the `node-fetch` package from NPM.

The analogous process in AWS Lambda is to package and upload your third-party dependencies, or deploy the packages to a Lambda Layer and configure your Lambda function to use that layer. Lambda will not `npm install node-fetch` for you.

Comment: AWS official guide to build deployment packages in different operating systems: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-nodejs/

Answer (score 2):

Simply add

```js
/* global fetch */
```

To the top of the index.mjs file in your lambda. That should work for you

Comment: i don't understand why this was voted down, it solved my same problem